# isNull(col, '')

Tags: c#, subsonic, case, isnull

How to write queries to do the followings in SubSonic/C#?

select isNull(col, someDefaultValue) from table

select x = 
   case
      when (condition) then col1
      else col2
   end
from table

Comment: Unclear question. Do you want to write the query in LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have SubSonic up and running locally, but it looks like it supports the coalesce function, which is what your first query seems to be doing. (Coalesce takes any number of parameters and returns the first non-null one.)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to want to use the Inline Query function example at [subsonicproject](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Inline_Query_Tool)